# catch exception without getting in its try block?

Tags: java, exception

I have an interesting issue.  My code block is given below. The problem is : log file does not contains  "Getting ready to sleep.." line but it contains "Backup thread was interrupted..." lines. 
My question : Is it possible to catch exception without getting in its try block ?

```
long sleepTime = runtime.getTimeInMillis() - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

try {
    log("Getting ready to sleep...(" + sleepTime + ")");

    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

    Database db = new Database();
    log(db.performDatabaseBackup());

    // Set it to run the next day.
    runtime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    log("Backup thread was interrupted...");
}
```

Edit  : Log method

```
  private void log(String message) {
                   Logger.debug(this, message);
}
```

and `Logger.debug`

```
public static void debug(
      Object obj,
      String message ){
      debug( obj.getClass(), message );
      }


    public static void debug(
      String className,
      String message )
   {
      try
      {
         Class inputClass = Class.forName( className );
         debug( inputClass, message );
      }
      catch ( ClassNotFoundException e )
      {
         debug( ( Class )null, message );
      }
   }
```

Comment: Short answer: no. There must be something else at work there. I recommend trying a remote debugger.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to catch an Exception not thrown during execution of its `try` block. Possible situations:

1. `InterruptedException` is thrown before you log `"Getting ready..."` i.e. in your `log(...)` call. (unlikely)
2. Log method does not work as expected and does not log your line. (likely) Can you check if the sleep is performed by setting a high sleep time. That would imply this reason.
3. You have other pieces of code logging `"Backup thread was interrupted..."` that cause the log output and the presented code fragement is not executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the log method is not functioning properly?  I don't believe that the catch block can be entered without entering the try block.  Another alternative is that the log method throws InterruptedException?

Can you post your log method as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter the `catch`block an exception has been thrown inside the `try` block. Period.

To solve your problem: Print the stacktrace of the exception and look if `log()` also throws some exceptions.